# Chain rule gradient Riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Suppose that $M$ is a Riemannian manifold and $s:M\to M$, $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ two given smooth maps.

> Is there a way to compute $\nabla(f\circ s)$?

where $\nabla$ is the gradient. I am looking for something like the usual chain rule in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In particular, I am trying to solve $\nabla(f\circ s)$ where $f$ is any smooth function, and $s(x)=\exp_x(\nabla \phi(x))$, for a potential $\phi:M\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Differential of a composition is composition of differentials, and gradient (as a column vector, i. e. map $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^m$) is dual w.r.t metric to differential.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please be more specific? I don’t understand the duality argument you are telling me. Is there an explict expression?

Comment: do you mean something like $(\nabla (f\circ s))^i=g^{ij}d(f\circ s)^j$? (where $g_{ij}$ is the metric). Can I simplify more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use the definition of gradient as the vector field equivalent to the differential: given $x \in M$ and $v \in T_xM$, we have $$g_x(\nabla(f\circ s)(x),v) = {\rm d}(f\circ s)_x(v) = {\rm d}f_{s(x)}({\rm d}s_x(v)) = g_{s(x)}(\nabla f(s(x)), {\rm d}s_x(v)) = g_x(({\rm d}s_x)^\top \nabla f(s(x)), v),$$so that $$\nabla(f\circ s)(x) = ({\rm d}s_x)^\top \big(\nabla f(s(x))\big),$$where $({\rm d}s_x)^\top \colon T_{s(x)}M \to T_xM$ is the adjoint map of ${\rm d}s_x\colon T_xM \to T_{s(x)}M$, characterized by the relation $$g_{s(x)}({\rm d}s_x(v), w) = g_x(v,({\rm d}s_x)^\top(w)), \qquad \forall\,v \in T_xM, \quad \forall\,w \in T_{s(x)}M.$$